# ¿Cuándo se usa “anda que si” o “anda que no”?

Tags: interjecciones

Me gustaría saber cuándo se usa "anda que...". Por ejemplo lo he visto en casos así:

> **Anda que si** te espero, no llego nunca a casa.
>
> **Anda que no** son listos.

Comment: ¿Dónde lo viste así?  Parece ser un regionalismo.

Comment: Lo saqué del libro que estoy usando para dominar el idioma

Comment: Perfecto, gracias.  ¿Pones el título y autor, por favor?  Y un enlace si existe en el internet.  Gracias.

Comment: Podría ser una manera de decir "Mira, que si te espero, entonces etc." tal vez.

Answer (score 5):

El uso de *anda* para este tipo de construcciones se trata en el [párrafo 32.1i](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bepdrvcykHkgCUHg) y siguientes de la *Gramática* de la RAE. En un principio se dice que esta y otras expresiones como *hala*, *hombre* o *venga* se pueden usar en contextos tanto apelativos como expresivos. Sin embargo, en el párrafo 32.1k se dice que varios autores han sugerido que esta clasificación binaria debería ampliarse, aunque no está claro cómo dado que se admiten un número de matices que sobrepasa as clasificaciones habituales de actos verbales.

> Así, con *anda* se invita o se estimula (*¡Anda, date prisa!*), se rechaza o se desestima (*¡Anda, anda! Déjate de tonterías*), se expresa asombro, sea real o afectado (*¡Anda este, con lo que sale ahora!*), se enfatiza (*¡Anda que no es listo!*), se advierte de un riesgo (*¡Anda que si empieza a llover...!*) o se replica a alguien con agresividad (*¡Anda que tú...!*).

Así, en tus ejemplos en el primer caso se advierte de un riesgo que habría tenido lugar en una situación hipotética:

> Anda que si te espero, no llego nunca a casa.
>   *Si te hubiera esperado, no habría llegado nunca a casa.*

Y en el segundo, que aparece en el texto extraído de la *Gramática*, el *anda* sirve para enfatizar:

> Anda que no son listos.
>   *Son muy listos.*

Nótese en este segundo caso el uso de una negación irónica para enfatizar aún más lo que se dice.